# Finding insect growth challenge

Tags: python

Alright, so I am in the middle of a challenge for my introduction to python class. I have been working with the bare minimum, and loops are giving the most trouble thus far. My prompt for the challenge is basically to write a program which doubles the number of insects as long as the input does not exceed 100. It might help if I paste the wording.

> Given positive integer num_insects, write a while loop that prints that number doubled up to, but without exceeding 100. Follow each number with a space.
>
> Sample output with input: 8
>
> ```
> 8 16 32 64
> ```

I know it is simple, but I have tried the following code thus far.

```
num_insects = int(input()) # Must be >= 1

while num_insects != 100:
num_insects = num_insects * 2
print(num_insects, end=' ')
```

This is not much, I agree. I've tried to use "num_insects >= 1" and even tried

```
num_insects = int(input()) # Must be >= 1

while num_insects >= 1 and num_insects <= 100:
num_insects = num_insects * 2
print(num_insects, end=' ')
```

Loops are giving me the hardest time so far. Can someone offer a bit of advice as to what I am doing wrong? Maybe there's a way to think of loops that keeps me from overthinking the concept altogether.

EDIT: Forgot to add, my code produces the output "16 32 64 128".

Thanks in Advance,

Joseph

Comment: Submitted an edit request with formatting for codeblocks.

Comment: Your code indentation is incorrect, you should be getting a syntax error.

Comment: Imagine if the input is 64 and follow through line by line *exactly* what the code is doing. It might help to have a pen and paper here to keep track of what variable is holding what value. If you try that the answer should be pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is almost right, except you're doubling the number after you check the limit and before printing. So you omit the first number, and then print the first number after 100.

```
while num_insects <= 100:
    print(num_insects, end=' ')
    num_insects *= 2
```